# php the most correct way to convert i:s minutes and seconds to seconds

Tags: php, function, date, time, seconds

date('i:s',600) will display ten minutes: 10:00. Nice and perfect. I don't care about hours.

I need the reverse function that gets 600 from the string `'10:00'`?

So, I'm looking for **the reverse function for `date('i:s',$secs)`**.

`$secs` could be any **correct** time of minutes and seconds displayed as a string from '00:00' to '59:59'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function reverse($secs) {
  list($i, $s) = explode(':', $secs);
  return $i*60 + $s;
}
```

Anything more is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how efficient `strtotime` is but you could do this:

```
function seconds($time)
{
    return (strtotime("00:" . $time) - strtotime("00:00:00"));
}
```